# Initialize ArrayList with a range of integer values avoiding loops

Tags: java, arraylist

I would like to initialize an ArrayList with a range of integer values. 
This is what I want to avoid:

```
ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i = 0; i < x; i++){
    numbers.add(i);
}
```

I found rangeClosed function for IntStream:

```
IntStream.rangeClosed(0, instance.getNumVertices()-1);
```

But I think that the conversiont to ArrayList won't be worth it.

I'm looking for efficiency...

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "efficiency"? Any method, whether you explicitly use a loop yourself or not, is likely to implement this using a loop. There's no magic way to initialize an array without some sort of loop. It's better to write clear and easy to understand code than to use tricks that you *think* are more efficient, without having *proof* that it somehow improves your program.

Comment: I agree but It may be possible not to generate the array elements until they are needed, although internally the program is aware of the elements it contains.

Answer (score 6):

The `ArrayList` is backed by an array. If you want to fill it with ascending values, you won't get any quicker than just iterating over those values and adding them to the list.

The only thing I'd change in your example is initialize the array with the already known size, so that it wouldn't spend time and memory on expansion of the underlying array:

```java
ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>(x);
for(int i = 0; i < x; i++){
    numbers.add(i);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
List<Integer> range100 = IntStream.range(0,100).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have an object that looks like a `List<Integer>` that contains numbers from 0 up to N without actually storing those numbers, then you can implement your own list, for example like this:

```
import java.util.AbstractList;

public class RangeList extends AbstractList<Integer> {
    private final int size;

    public RangeList(int size) {
        this.size = size;
    }

    @Override
    public Integer get(int index) {
        return index;
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return size;
    }
}
```

You can create an instance of it like this:

```
List<Integer> numbers = new RangeList(10);
```

It behaves just like a standard `ArrayList<Integer>` containing the values 0 to 9, but you cannot modify the list (adding, removing, modifying entries will lead to an `UnsupportedOperationException`).

Answer (score 1):

No matter how you decide to fill the ArrayList you will have to loop over or use each value that is stored into the ArrayList one by one. There is no faster way then iterating over each value and adding it to the ArrayList, only ways that make it look cleaner.

Creating a function that does so, or a an extension of the ArrayList object are two ways of doing so.

```
private ArrayList<Integer> fillRange(int min, int max){
    ArrayList<Integer> a_lst = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i = min; i < max; i++){
        a_lst.add(i);
    }
    return a_lst;
}
```